# Reset bitcoin blockchain checkpoint to mine 0th block

Tags: blockchain, testnet, genesis-block, checkpoints

I want to start a new block chain and mine the 0th block, but I guess the hardcoded checkpoint in `chainparams.cpp` won't allow that.

I guess I need to reset the `checkpoint` hardcoded as follows before starting a new blockchain.

```
    checkpointData = (CCheckpointData){
        boost::assign::map_list_of
        ( 0, uint256S("000000000933ea01ad0ee984209779baaec3ced90fa3f408719526f8d77f4943")),
        0,
        0,
        0
    };
```